# Mootools class protected handler?

Tags: javascript, class, mootools, protected

As a flash developer, i try to have the same flexibility as AS3 provide with mootools.

I try to do a simple thing, create an event handler function that be protected.
I hate to write inline function so i writte something like this:

```
//CLASS DEFINITION AS USUAL
    initializeEvent:function (){


    if (this.options.slider) this.options.slider.addEvents ({

        mousedown:function (e){

            this.sliderDownHandler();
            //throw an error because sliderDownHandler is set to protected

        }


    });

},

update:function (){

    this.fireEvent('update');

}.protect(),

sliderDownHandler:function (e){

    this.update();
    console.log ('yeah it down')

}.protect();
```

Without the .protect() the handler work as expected.

It's possible to reach this goal with the .protected() ?

Many thank!

Answer (score 1):

sure you can. you have a binding error, not a problem with protected

```
mousedown:function (e){
    this.sliderDownHandler();
    //throw an error because sliderDownHandler is set to protected
}
```

no. it is throwing an error because `this` will be bound to `this.options.slider`, which fired the event - which I guess is an element that has no `sliderDownHandler` method. the exception you get on a protected method is quite unique and is no mistaking it - try it by calling it externally on `instance.sliderDownHandler()`

re-write as one of these:

```
var self = this;
...
mousedown:function (e){
    self.sliderDownHandler();
}

// or, bind the event to the class instance method...
mousedown: this.sliderDownloadHandler.bind(this)
```